# Why algorithm performance differs

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have to implement a 'range' function in javascript like the one in python.

```
function range (x, y, i){
    i = i || 1;

    j = [x];
    while (y > (x+i)) {
        j.push(x += i);
    }
    return j;
}

function range2 (x, y, i){
    i = i|| 1;

    j = [];
    for (x ; x < y; x += i) {
        j.push(x);
    };
    return j;
}
```

Seems the second one works better. Always, there is a better approach to a problem in many scenarios but why is it so ? What is making the first range function slower , or what's making the second one faster ?

Comment: `Seems the second one works better` - How?

Comment: They have exactly the same complexity.

Comment: is it the fact that for loop is better than while loop or vice versa ?

Answer (score 2):

Because you are calling a function inside your first function. This is extra overhead.

A function call does not really incur a high performance cost, and this is just micro optimisation. For this case, the two sets of implementation should roughly take the same time.

Comment: Ok, removed the function but still there's difference in the performance of the two algorithms

Answer (score 2):

The main difference (performance wise) between the functions is that the first one is making a function call for every iteration in the loop.

Although function calls are not very expensive, when you do it in a loop like this where there is little work in each iteration, it will add substantially to the work being done.

Note that there is also a difference in the result from the implementations. The first function will always return an array with at least one item, even if `y` is less than `x`, while the second function returns an empty array in that case. Also the first function includes all values that are `<= y` while the second includes all values that are `< y`. It doesn't matter which implementation is faster, if it doesn't return the correct result.

#### Edit:

When you remove the function call, the performance difference between the functions is very small:

http://jsperf.com/range-for-vs-while

I added an implementation using `while` that is the exact equivalent of the code with the `for` loop:

```
function range3 (x, y, i){
    i = i|| 1;
    
    j = [];
    x;
    while (x < y) {
        j.push(x);
        x += i;
    };
    return j;
}
```

Chrome runs this implementation slightly faster for some reason, in other browsers the performance is identical.

Comment: updated, no function call now

Comment: @SnorkS: That makes the performance difference minimal. I added a performance test in the answer.

Comment: does that mean while loop is better ? atleast for chrome ?

Comment: and the range and range3 functions being more or less same, why is range3 faster ?

Comment: @SnorkS: No, it only means that this exact implementation works slightly better in Chrome. Any small change in the code may reverse the situation. As you see in the small differences between `range` and `range3` (the `x+i` in the condition and the `x += i` used inside the method call) it's nearly impossible to predict exactly how the code will perform. All this is micro-optimisation, and especially in Javascript that is a futile endeavour.